# How to obtain data from UDP with Java?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-programming, udp

I am new to Network Engineering and I had an assignment as the following. An external device is sending a UDP Packet to my computer  every 1 second. I want to use an information in that UDP packet. As the socket interface I use Java programming language. I try to write a code to do this assignment.  However, I can not see any of the data even though I can see the UDP packets via Wireshark.Destination port number is 876 in the UDP packet as I see it from Wireshark. Following is the code that I wrote. I also close the Firewalls of my computer. Can anyone help me why is this happening?

```
import java.io.*;

import java.net.*;

public class UDPReceive {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(876);
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[102];
        System.out.println("1");

        while(true){
            System.out.println("2");
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            System.out.println("3");
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            System.out.println("4");
            String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
            System.out.println("5");
            System.out.println(sentence);
        }
    }
}
```

The code does not print "4" but prints 1,2,3.

Comment: What do you mean by "Ethernet cable?" Ethernet runs on a variety of media (coax, UTP, STP, fiber optics-both MM and SM). There is no such thing as an ethernet cable because all those media can be used for other protocols, too.

Comment: The device that I interface with my computer has a cable that plugs to my computer via Ethernet port like Internet Port. I get the information from there and can see the packets in Wireshark. Therefore, I do not think that the type is important. I am wondering even though I can see the packets why cant I obtain them with the given code.

Comment: There is nothing in the code that is specific to a cable, or even to ethernet. A UDP datagram is sent to IP (either IPv4 or IPv6) which encapsulates the datagram into an IP packet, which is then sent to the data-link protocol (ethernet, in your case), which encapsulates the packet into a frame, then the frame is sent to the physical interface, where it is encoded into bits on the wire. UDP does not know or care about the data-link protocol or physical interface.

Comment: Okey sorry for the irrelavent information but my question is totally different, I see the code that I give in many different websites in which the main objective is to obtain the UDP packet. However,  I cannot do it in my computer. Thats why I asked the question.

Comment: You *closed* the firewall? And you still expect to receive data through it?

Comment: Yes, because I also tried the other way(not closing the firewall) and there is still no data recieved. In both cases I can see the datagram packet in Wireshark